# Vertical centering in tabularx after forced \newline

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-breaking, tabularx, cell

I am having troubles with a vertical alignement in cells after forcing \newline.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
        \footnotesize
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2mm}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[h!]{ 
           >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm} 
           >{\centering\arraybackslash}X            
           >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.33cm}        
           >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.33cm}    
           >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.33cm}        
           >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.33cm}    
           >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}     
           >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.6cm}    
           >{\centering\arraybackslash}X            
           }
        \hline
        & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Properties} & More\\ \cline{3-8}
            
        Name & Prop. \newline(Unit1) & Prop. \newline(Unit2) & Prop. \newline(Unit3) & Prop. \newline(Unit4) & Prop. \newline(Unit5) & Prop. \newline(Unit6) &  Prop. \newline(Unit7) & Prop. \newline(Unit8)\\
        
        \hline
        long name1 & 147\newline$\pm$\ 3 & 64\newline$\pm$\ 2 & 423\newline$\pm$\ 5    & 426\newline$\pm$\ 5   & 6\newline$\pm$\ 2 & 22\newline$\pm$\ 2    & 1.90\newline$\pm$\ 0.08   
                                                                                                                                                        & 386\newline$\pm$\ 17 \\
        
        long name2   & 174\newline$\pm$\ 3 & 73\newline$\pm$\ 3 & 551\newline$\pm$\ 3      & 556\newline$\pm$\ 6   & 80\newline$\pm$\ 3         & 18\newline$\pm$\ 1     & 2.63\newline$\pm$\ 0.11  &                                                                                                                                                                     548\newline$\pm$\ 37 \\
        long name3   & 225\newline$\pm$\ 3 & 77\newline$\pm$\ 3 & 678\newline$\pm$\ 9      & 675\newline$\pm$\ 8   & 485\newline$\pm$\ 23       & 17\newline$\pm$\ 2     & 3.66\newline$\pm$\ 0.17                                                                                                                                                                      & 607\newline$\pm$\ 17 \\
        long name4   & 228\newline$\pm$\ 3 & 78\newline$\pm$\ 3 & 602\newline$\pm$\ 10     & 606\newline$\pm$\ 9   & 373\newline$\pm$\ 36       & 30\newline$\pm$\ 2     & 2.92\newline$\pm$\ 0.09  
                                                                                                                                                                            & 604\newline$\pm$\ 18 \\
        long name5   & 232\newline$\pm$\ 5 & 82\newline$\pm$\ 2 & 620\newline$\pm$\ 2      & 618\newline$\pm$\ 5   & 407\newline$\pm$\ 47       & 32\newline$\pm$\ 3     & 2.95\newline$\pm$\ 0.06                                                                                                                                                                     & 568\newline$\pm$\ 12 \\
        
        long name6  & 184\newline$\pm$\ 4 & 75\newline$\pm$\ 0 & 547\newline$\pm$\ 9      & 548\newline$\pm$\ 9   & 96\newline$\pm$\ 40        & 13\newline$\pm$\ 2     & 2.40\newline$\pm$\ 0.07  
                                                                                                                                                                            & 487\newline$\pm$\ 11 \\
        long name7  & 223\newline$\pm$\ 4 & 73\newline$\pm$\ 2 & 539\newline$\pm$\ 10     & 544\newline$\pm$\ 10  & 63\newline$\pm$\ 37        & 28\newline$\pm$\ 3     & 2.51\newline$\pm$\ 0.05  
                                                                                                                                                                            & 525\newline$\pm$\ 14 \\
        long name8     & 268\newline$\pm$\ 5 &   \multicolumn{6}{c}{A very long sentence}      & 622\newline$\pm$\ 124 \\
        long name9   & 290\newline$\pm$\ 5 &   \multicolumn{6}{c}{A very long sentence 2}      & 639\newline$\pm$\ 44 \\
        
        long name10  & 202\newline$\pm$\ 5 & 78\newline$\pm$\ 2 & 596\newline$\pm$\ 10     & 612\newline$\pm$\ 9   & 309\newline$\pm$\ 37  & 22\newline$\pm$\ 2    & 2.86\newline$\pm$\ 0.07   
                                                                                                                                                                          & 729\newline$\pm$\ 29 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabularx}

    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

which gives the following image.
As you can see in every column, the new forced line in each cell (where there is "± n°") is not vertically aligned to the value above.
I specifically want the "± n°" on the second line; the same for the second row: "Prop. (Unit)", also not aligned.

I have tried several options but can't figure it out.
Help would be very much appreciated.
Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `X` columns in all columns except in the first. Also I would remove word "Prop." from column headers (it seems that they are just repetition of first row test). By using `tabularray` instead of `tabičlarex` the table code is shorter and more clear, also can be used normal font size:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
%\footnotesute
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z}=1pt, hline{3}=solid,
             colsep=4pt,
             colspec={@{} l *{8}{X[c,font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont]} @{}},
             }
        &   &  \SetCell[c=6]{c} Properties
                &   &   &   &   &   &   More            \\
        \cline{2-8}
Name    & Unit 1    & Unit 2    & Unit 3    & Unit 4 
        & Unit 5    & Unit 6    & Unit 7    & Unit 8    \\
long name 1  
        & {147\\ $\pm 3$} & {64\\ $\pm 2$} & {423\\  $\pm 5$}    & {426\\ $\pm 5$}
        & {  6\\ $\pm 2$} & {22\\ $\pm 2$} & {1.90\\ $\pm 0.08$} & {386\\ $\pm 17$}     \\
long name 2  
        & {174\\ $\pm 3$} & {73\\ $\pm 3$} & {551\\ $\pm 3$}     & {556\\ $\pm 6$}
        & {80\\ $\pm 3$}  & {18\\ $\pm 1$} & {2.63\\ $\pm 0.11$} & {548\\ $\pm 37$}     \\
long name 3
        & {225\\ $\pm 3$}  & {77\\ $\pm 3$} & {678\\ $\pm 9$}     & {675\\ $\pm 8$}
        & {485\\ $\pm 23$} & {17\\ $\pm 2$} & {3.66\\ $\pm 0.17$} & {607\\ $\pm 17$}    \\
long name 4
        & {228\\ $\pm 3$}  & {78\\ $\pm 3$} & {602\\ $\pm 10$}   & {606\\ $\pm 9$}   
        & {373\\ $\pm 36$} & {30\\ $\pm 2$} & {2.92\\ $\pm 0.09$} & {604\\ $\pm 18$} \\
long name 5
        & {232\\ $\pm 5$}  & {82\\ $\pm 2$} & {620\\ $\pm 2$}     & {618\\ $\pm 5$}
        & {407\\ $\pm 47$} & {32\\ $\pm 3$} & {2.95\\ $\pm 0.06$} & {568\\ $\pm 12$}
        \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In table body are only first 5 rows, others you can edit yourself on showed way.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The main source of the trouble is that you're setting the widths of most of the 8 data columns too narrow. I suggest you employ just one type-`X` column, for the labels in column 1, and set the widths of the 8 data columns to the width of one of the header labels, say, `(Unit2)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \Centering macro
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{(Unit2)}  % width of the 8 data columns

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X *{8}{>{\Centering}p{\mylen}} @{}}
        \hline
        & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Properties} & More\\
        \cline{3-8}
        Name
        & Prop. \newline(Unit1) & Prop. \newline(Unit2) & Prop. \newline(Unit3) & Prop. \newline(Unit4)
        & Prop. \newline(Unit5) & Prop. \newline(Unit6) & Prop. \newline(Unit7) & Prop. \newline(Unit8) \\
        \hline
        long name1  & 147\newline$\pm$ 3 & 64\newline$\pm$ 2 & 423\newline$\pm$ 5    & 426\newline$\pm$ 5   & 6\newline$\pm$ 2      & 22\newline$\pm$ 2 & 1.90\newline$\pm$ 0.08 & 386\newline$\pm$ 17 \\
        long name2  & 174\newline$\pm$ 3 & 73\newline$\pm$ 3 & 551\newline$\pm$ 3    & 556\newline$\pm$ 6   & 80\newline$\pm$ 3     & 18\newline$\pm$ 1 & 2.63\newline$\pm$ 0.11 & 548\newline$\pm$ 37 \\
        long name3  & 225\newline$\pm$ 3 & 77\newline$\pm$ 3 & 678\newline$\pm$ 9    & 675\newline$\pm$ 8   & 485\newline$\pm$ 23   & 17\newline$\pm$ 2 & 3.66\newline$\pm$ 0.17 & 607\newline$\pm$ 17 \\
        long name4  & 228\newline$\pm$ 3 & 78\newline$\pm$ 3 & 602\newline$\pm$ 10   & 606\newline$\pm$ 9   & 373\newline$\pm$ 36   & 30\newline$\pm$ 2 & 2.92\newline$\pm$ 0.09 & 604\newline$\pm$ 18 \\
        long name5  & 232\newline$\pm$ 5 & 82\newline$\pm$ 2 & 620\newline$\pm$ 2    & 618\newline$\pm$ 5   & 407\newline$\pm$ 47   & 32\newline$\pm$ 3 & 2.95\newline$\pm$ 0.06 & 568\newline$\pm$ 12 \\
        long name6  & 184\newline$\pm$ 4 & 75\newline$\pm$ 0 & 547\newline$\pm$ 9    & 548\newline$\pm$ 9   & 96\newline$\pm$ 40    & 13\newline$\pm$ 2 & 2.40\newline$\pm$ 0.07 & 487\newline$\pm$ 11 \\
        long name7  & 223\newline$\pm$ 4 & 73\newline$\pm$ 2 & 539\newline$\pm$ 10   & 544\newline$\pm$ 10  & 63\newline$\pm$ 37    & 28\newline$\pm$ 3 & 2.51\newline$\pm$ 0.05 & 525\newline$\pm$ 14 \\
        long name8  & 268\newline$\pm$ 5 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{A very long sentence}  & 622\newline$\pm$ 124 \\
        long name9  & 290\newline$\pm$ 5 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{A very long sentence 2}& 639\newline$\pm$  44 \\
        long name10 & 202\newline$\pm$ 5 & 78\newline$\pm$ 2 & 596\newline$\pm$ 10    & 612\newline$\pm$ 9  & 309\newline$\pm$ 37   & 22\newline$\pm$ 2 & 2.86\newline$\pm$ 0.07 & 729\newline$\pm$ 29 \\
        \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```